# Kivy: Why does it show "Unknown class" when i have already identified all classes

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

This question already exists on stackoverflow but the solutions for them didnt worked for me.

Based on what i read online this error occurs, when there is an unidentified child widget in the kv file, but i have already identified all my widgets in the 'py' file

I have tried moving down the "Builder.load_file" (by down i mean after the class-es) and it worked properly, but then i couldnt bind widgets with functions, it showed some other error. So this was not a permanent solution.

important parts of my 'py' and 'kv' files

py:

```
kv = Builder.load_file("pcapp.kv")


class ActionBar(ActionBar):
    pass


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Screen_one(Screen):
    pass


class Screen_two(Screen):
    pass


class GoodsView(ScrollView):
    pass


class Screen_three(Screen):
    pass


class CalculatorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv
```

kv:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: .65, .75, .85, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    ActionBar:
        ...
     Manager:
        id: sm
        Screen_one:
            id: screen_one
            name: 'screen1'
            manager: 'sm'
        Screen_two:
            id: screen_two
            name: 'screen2'
            manager: 'sm'
        Screen_three:
            id: screen_three
            name: 'screen3'
            manager: 'sm'
<Screen_one>:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Click1"
            size_hint: .2, .05
            pos_hint: {'x': .2, 'y': .4}
            on_release: app.root.ids.sm.current  = 'screen2'
        Label:
            text: 'Hello!'
            pos_hint: {'x': -0.2, 'y': 0}

<Screen_two>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

        GoodsView:


<GoodsView>:
          ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error, `kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <Manager>` because in the kv file, when it is creating the root it tries to instantiate the child, `Manager:` object but it could not find the implementation of `class Manager()` before the `Builder.load_file()` function.

## Solution

1. Remove `kv = Builder.load_file("pcapp.kv")`
2. Replace `return kv` with `return Builder.load_file("pcapp.kv")`

Comment: Dude you are amazing! Thank you!